# Run code javascript: Como elaborar um ambiente que execute o código Javascript fornecido pelo usuário?

Tags: javascript, runtime

Estou com dúvida em como executar um código em javascript, fornecido pelo usuário da plataforma, como no exemplo do site a seguir: https://js.do/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o comando `eval('expressão')` que executa a expressão passada como string (texto). https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

No entanto, o site que você indicou, utiliza o comando

```
var doc = document.getElementById('result').contentDocument;
doc.open();
doc.write(code);
doc.close();
```

Onde o elemento `result` é um `iframe`. Ou seja, ele abre o documento iframe, escreve o conteúdo digitado pelo usuário (javascript) e fecha o documento. Desta forma o navegador recarrega o iframe com novo conteúdo inserido. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp

Comment: Fiz alguns testes com o comando eval(), e consegui ter resultados, funcionou bem no meu projeto. Muito obrigado.